# imagemagick: How to crop a picture and paste it elsewhere on the same picture?

Tags: crop, offset, imagemagick-convert

**What I want:**

Using `ImageMagick` I crop a part of the picture and then paste it somewhere else on the same picture.

Eg:
[image]

**What I tried:**

`convert in.jpg -page +0+300 \( -clone 0 -crop 650x600+0+300 \) -flatten out.jpg`

Result:
[image]

**The issue:**

The cropping starts from (0,0) of the image. I can't figure out a way use an offset.

How can I crop a portion that is in the middle of a picture and paste it somewhere else on the same picture using `ImageMagick`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ImageMagick, you do that using -gravity and -geometry with -composite.

Here I set -gravity center for the crop, then -gravity northwest for the composite. I crop a region from the center and move it to the right:

```
convert pic.jpg \
\( +clone -gravity center -crop 650x600+0+0 +repage \) \
-gravity northwest -geometry +1200+300 \
-compose over -composite result.jpg
```

[image]

Here I set -gravity center for the crop, then -gravity center for the composite. I crop a region from the center and move it to the right.

```
convert pic.jpg \
\( +clone -gravity center -crop 650x600+0+0 +repage \) \
-gravity center -geometry +500-100 \
-compose over -composite result2.jpg
```

[image]